# Android Webbrowser control

Tags: android, automation, browser

Could somebody tell me what type of class I have to use to create a Webbrowser and automate activity in Android?
I was looking for a class without matching a satisfying result.
Thanks!

Comment: What does "automate activity" mean?

Comment: Any type of activity someone could do with his Webbrowser and can be automated -> "Automate activity" <- ¿Automation?

Comment: You may have better luck using an Android developer support site in a language that is more comfortable for you. I have many such sites listed at http://www.andglobe.com. Otherwise, please explain what sort of "activity" you wish to "automate".

Answer (score 0):

I need to take WebView and create a WebViewClient instance to display URL inside that WebView.

Note that, in order for your Activity to access the Internet and load web pages in a WebView, you must add the INTERNET permissions to your Android Manifest file:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```